# Does the elven stronghold in Mirkwood have a proper name?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

In the Hobbit the dwarves are captured by elves in Mirkwood and taken to a stronghold on the northeastern side of Mirkwood along the Forest River referred to as "The Elvenking's Halls".

[image: A map of the Wilderland from Christopher Tolkien]

Image credit: http://tolkiengateway.net/w/images/2/20/Christopher_Tolkien_-_Map_of_Wilderland.jpg

Does this stronghold/settlement have a proper elven name other than "The Elvenking's Halls" (like Caras Galadhon in Lothlorien)? Do the elves of Mirkwood not have proper names for their settlements?

Comment: http://tolkiengateway.net/w/images/2/20/Christopher_Tolkien_-_Map_of_Wilderland.jpg

Comment: @Valorum Thanks for the map, I have added it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Halls of Thranduil

I do not believe they are given a separate title in most of Tolklien's works or writings. This is kind of odd as one would expect a Sindarian name at the very least; it might be safe to assume that such a title does exist (in universe) however, this title has yet to be extrapolated (to my knowledge).

There is a very detailed answer given [Here](https://www.quora.com/Are-the-halls-of-Thranduil-ever-given-a-name)